# explicit template instantiation in main function

Tags: c++, templates

I have some toy codes as follow:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
template<typename T>
class MyClass{
    T t;
};
template class MyClass<int>;
int main()
{
    //template class MyClass<int>;
    return 0;
}
```

and:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
template<typename T>
class MyClass{
    T t;
};
//template class MyClass<int>;
int main()
{
    template class MyClass<int>;
    return 0;
}
```

`template class MyClass<int>;`inside the main() function didn't work.The error is error: expected primary-expression before 'template'
But the same statement outside the main() function works.Why this happen?

Comment: Dare I ask, what is the point of the latter? I mean, Is there a *reason* you think you need this?

Comment: What's even the point of trying to limit the scope of an explicit instantiation to a single function?

Comment: I'm reading David Vandevoorde's C++ templates: the complete guide 6.2.1.I happened to write `template class MyClass<int>` inside the main() function.There is no special reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd think this statement in 14.7.2 [temp.explicit] paragraph 3 means that explicit template instantiations have to appear at namespace scope:

> ... An explicit instantiation shall appear in an enclosing namespace of its template. ...

The implication is that you cannot explicitly instantiated templates with function-locale types. Since the intention of explicit template instantiations is avoiding multiple instantiations of templates repeatedly used with a just a few types, e.g., instantiating the stream types, this restriction isn't constraining.